# JQuery scope within nested functions

Tags: jquery, scope

This works:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#inputbuttonid").on("click", function(){ 

        var inputtext = $("#inputtextid").val();
        alert(inputtext);

    });

});
```

But this doesn't work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var inputtext = $("#inputtextid").val();

    $("#inputbuttonid").on("click", function(){ 

        alert(inputtext);

    });

});
```

By "works" I mean it alerts the correct information.

The only difference in the above 2 cases is that in the second, I put

```
var inputtext = $("#inputtextid").val();
```

in the outer function, whereas in the first, I put it in the inner function.

According to the JQuery manual, "local scope works through functions", meaning "any functions defined within another have access to variables defined in the outer function" (quoted from the JQuery manual).

So, why in the second case above, does the inner function not have access to "inputtext"?

Comment: That works perfectly fine -> http://jsfiddle.net/pVJ3L/2/

Comment: ... but if you're expecting the value to magically update itself, it wont!

Comment: it would "magically" update if you used something like knockout.js (bindings), but yes, as written; no magic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So, why in the second case above, does the inner function not have access to "inputtext"?

It does have access<sup>1</sup>, but you are executing the statement **before** the user entered a value. The value is read immediately when the DOM is ready, not when the user clicks the button.

> The only difference in the above 2 cases is that in the second, I put [...] in the outer function, whereas in the first, I put it in the inner function.

And this change has the consequence that that statement is now executed at a different *time*, at which the input field doesn't have a value yet.

---

1: If it didn't, you would get a reference error.

Comment: Excellent, thanks. I'll mark your answer right as soon as SO lets me :-)

Comment: Serious question: I just noticed your SO score. Is your brain sufficiently trained that you read code like you were reading Shakespeare, and you dream in code?

Answer (score 0):

In the 2nd example, your variable is initialized on document load, and there's no code in the click function to get the new value. This would work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var inputtext = $("#inputtextid").val();

    $("#inputbuttonid").on("click", function(){ 
        inputtext = $("#inputtextid").val();
        alert(inputtext);

    });

});
```